# How does upper_bound() work if only a less-than comparator is defined?

Tags: c++

I was given a class that is built on top of a map with the following K type and V type limitations:

- `K`: copyable, assignable, is less-than comparable (`<`). Does not implement any other operations (no equality comparison or arithmetic operators)
- `V`: copyable, assignable, equality-comparable (`==`). Does not implement any other operations.

Given that limitation, wouldn't this code not work?

```
auto it = map.upper_bound(K);
```

Since `upper_bound()` (as defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound)) returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is **greater than** key. Meaning the K would use a greater-than comparator?

Or does it follow that a definition of a less-than comparator would also define a greater-than comparator?

Or is my understanding of how `upper_bound()` works wrong?

Comment: @NicolBolas By what definition does `a < b` mean that `b > a`?

Comment: I believe you would get the first element `y` such that `key < y`.  That's what "greater than" means in this context.  Not the first `y` such that `y > key`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @NicolBolas can you link me a documentation that explicitly states that? I mean, common sense-wise that works, but I assume that C++ wouldn't understand that kind of logic unless explicitly told to. Basing from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison), it only takes the `rhs` and `lhs` separately for `>` and `<`operators

Comment: @NateEldredge oh that makes sense! Edit: upon further search the documentation of upper_bound() [seems to agree with you](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) Thank you!

Comment: A simple answer is that for `std::map` you need [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) of keys. You need only **one** operator to establish such ordering, and by convention `operator<` is used everywhere. For example, if logically you need a condition `a > b`, technically you write it as `b < a`.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Nate Eldredge:

> I believe you would get the first element y such that key < y. That's
> what "greater than" means in this context. Not the first y such that y > key

and from [C++ documentation of upper_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/):

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
ForwardIterator upper_bound (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
{
 ForwardIterator it;
 iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type count, step;
 count = std::distance(first,last);
 while (count>0)
{
    it = first; step=count/2; std::advance (it,step);
    if (!(val<*it))                 // or: if (!comp(val,*it)), for version (2)
      { first=++it; count-=step+1;  }
    else count=step;
  }
  return first;
}
```

upper_bound() uses a `<` operator for comparison or to be more specific this:`!(val<*it)`

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I had a similar confusion.
I realize it just swaps the left hand side and right hand side of the operator.

Let elementToSearch be the element you're searching for and elementInSortedList be an element in the sorted list of elements.

With just the less than operator defined,

lower_bound returns the first element that is
NOT(elementToSearch < elementInSortedList). Hence, it will return the first element in the sorted list that is >= elementToSearch

upper_bound returns the first element that is
(elementToSearch < elementInSortedList).
Hence, it will return the first element in the sorted list that is strictly > elementToSearch.